# Azure VHD blobs larger than 1TB

Tags: azure, cloud, blob, azure-storage

Azure storage supports blobs up to 1 TB in size, which accommodates a VHD with a maximum virtual size of 999 GB.

I want to create a VHD for your database system that uses several blobs to accommodate databases larger than 1 TB, is this possible? And if so, then how can I configure a single VHD to use different blobs?

Answer (score 1):

Win2012? From azure portal, create and attach N disks (1 TB each?) to you virtual machine. Then, from win2012 create a StoregePool and create a virtual disk on it. The resulting size is the sum of disks size if you choose the "Simple" layout (or less if you choose Mirror or Parity). Details: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yungchou/archive/2012/08/31/windows-server-2012-storage-virtualization-explained.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/06/04/the-top-10-things-to-know-when-running-sql-server-workloads-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

> A data disk can be up to 1 TB in size, and you can have a maximum of
>   16 drives on an A4 or larger VM. If your database is larger than 1 TB,
>   you can use SQL Server [file groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) to spread your database across
>   multiple data disks. Alternatively, you can combine multiple data
>   disks into a single large volume using [Storage Spaces](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739.aspx) in Windows
>   Server 2012. Storage Spaces are better than legacy OS striping
>   technologies because they work well with the append-only nature of
>   Windows Azure Storage.